# Change woocommerce "Add to cart" button function to just foward to the product page instead

Tags: php, function, woocommerce

Hi i want to change the function of the add to cart button function, to just forward to the product page instead, and not add to cart

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_loop_add_to_cart_link', 'redirect_to_product_page', 10, 2 );
 
function redirect_to_product_page( $link, $product ) {
    global $woocommerce;
    $product_cat = wp_get_post_terms( $product->get_id(), 'product_cat', array( 'fields' => 'slugs' ) );
    $product_cat = isset( $product_cat[0] ) ? $product_cat[0] : '';
    $link = get_site_url() . '/product/' . $product_cat . '/' . $product->get_slug() . '/';
    return $link;
}
```

this is the code i've tried but it's just replacing the add to cart with the correct url

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the button and then put it back with your own info. This will also allow you to change the button text:

```
add_action('init', 'remove_loop_button');
function remove_loop_button(){
    remove_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart', 10);
}

add_action('woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'replace_add_to_cart');
function replace_add_to_cart() {
    global $product;
    $button_text = 'View Product';
    echo '<a class ="button product_type_simple add_to_cart_button ajax_add_to_cart" href="' . $product->get_permalink() . '">' . $button_text . '</a><br/>';
}
```